# Is there a way to spill horizontally in a table?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to return multiple values horizontally into a table from another table (vertical array).

I found 2 formulas  :

```
= transpose(filter(Result array, x = validation array))
```

or something like that

```
=INDEX($C$5:$C$14, SMALL(IF($B$16=$B$5:$B$14,ROW($B$5:$B$14)-ROW($B$5)+1), COLUMN(A1)))
```

The first one is more neat and works perfectly except that it won't allow me to spill in the receiving table..since it's in a table.
The second one kind of works but isn't so clean and I will need my table to add lines in a dynamic way so the first one would be easier.

Do you guys know any work around that spill in a table error thing?

Thank you

Comment: Spill formulas are not permitted within tables. Can you not work with spilling the results into a non-table range? The alternative would be to use VBA to first determine the number of columns by which the table should be resized and then populating those columns accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!
I do have a fix number of columns in the receiving table. I will rethink my approach and evaluate the possibility of a macro. I was trying to avoid it as I have a few already in my workbook. Thanks again for your answer.